# Vuelidate: Make field optional based on other checkbox (should apply to custom validations as well)

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuelidate

How to keep a field optional in Vuelidate?

Vuelidate gives `$v` in code. To check form validation we have `$invalid` prop
Now how do I keep x field optional based on checkbox thing
eg.

```
[ ] use y field
[ y text field ] (right now optional)
```

but if i check the checkbox

```
[x] use y field
[ y text field ] (now its required and it will follow other validations such as sameAs/minLength/max/custom validation
```

PS: It should also validate custom validations as well.

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5txk0e8c/).
What I want is, If I check the `is universal` box then only validations should apply over the input box else the validations should be ignored and `$invalid` should be `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change your `validations` property to a function, this will let you to access state using `this`. also you need to check your checkbox value in your custom validators too:

```
validations() {
  return {
    text: {
        required: requiredIf(function () {
        return this.isUniversal
      }),
      roblox (val) {
        return this.isUniversal ? !!val.match(/roblox.com/) : true
      }
    }
  }
},
```

i edited your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we13tpg0/2)

Comment: Amazing thanks alot <3. I was wondering why `this` isnt getting reactively/properly working.